# How can I reserve the IPs to the hosts in strongswan?

Tags: vpn, strongswan

For Example: when host "91:75:1a:ec:9a:c7" connect for first time assign IP "10.19.48.15"

when host "88:23:yd:q2:9y:b3" connect for first time assign IP "10.19.48.16"

and if they disconnect, next time they get the same IP. is there a way to recerve or increase the lifetime the IP to the hosts?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you think the MAC address of these clients is relevant? The VPN server will never see them (unless the clients are in the same LAN). Virtual IPs are assigned based on a client's identity (check the strongSwan log for details). Regarding assigning static virtual IPs, have a look at the different available backends documented on [[the strongSwan wiki](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp#Responder-Configuration).

Comment: Im not think the MAC address of these clients is relevant, just put the mac address  to indicate that the clients are diferents, I want to asign the ip to certain host/clients, Im a complete beginer here, I never configure strongswan before, I search on youtube and Docs but not have a idea how to modify or do it the changes,  I use strongswan by creating the VPN with Algo VPN, if there is some problem with the question I'm able to delete it.

Comment: You need to check what plugins are available with Algo and then configure them accordingly (see the link I gave above). Also consider just going with dynamically assigned addresses. Or do you have a particular reason for always assigning the same IPs?

Comment: I need to connect two Applications over internet, one of them is on a PC (Server) and other are on iOS or Android devices (Terminals), so if I turn off my PC (Server) and star again (or restart) sometimes strongswan change the IP, so then I need to re-configure the terminals (iOS, android) with the new PC IP Address.

Comment: If the Algo server is based on Ubuntu, you can install the _libstrongswan-extra-plugins_ package, which provides the [attr-sql](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/AttrSQL) and _sqlite_ plugins. That will allow you to statically define leases for specific client identities (e.g. via the [ipsec pool](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Ipsecpool) utility).